# how to change variable name dynamically?

Tags: r

I have this expression:

```
dat$we$VAR = iif(test252.2 > test5.2 & test252.1 < test5.1 & test252 < test5, -1, dat$we$VAR)
```

what I want is to make `VAR` dynamic.

For example `VAR = names(mydata)[1]`

Note that `dat$we$VAR` is also at the end of `iif` function

Answer (score 0):

```
var = "VAR"
dat$we[[var]] = iif(test252.2 > test5.2 & test252.1 < test5.1 & test252 < test5, -1, dat$we[[var]])
```

Comment: doesn't work.  Don't know if matter, but dat$we$VAR is an xts object

Comment: Then you should have said that it was an its object as otherwise it reads like a list or a data.frame, for which the syntax I described would work. The fact that it does not work for its probably means that the developers have only implemented the $ operator, but not the [[.